# Get objectId after parse.push.subscribe

Tags: trigger.io, parse-platform

I am building a Trigger.io app and am using Parse for push notifications. Everything works great; however, I need to get the objectId of my installations. I know that if I use the parse API directly the response body is a JSON object containing the objectId and the createdAt timestamp of the newly-created installation. Is there a way to get this if I use forge.partners.parse.push.subscribe?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get the details of installations by simply using the Parse REST API for it:
https://www.parse.com/docs/rest

Comment: I still can't retrieve the details of the installation without knowing its objectId (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#installations-retrieving). Is there a way to retrieve the details of installation from the device/phone?

Comment: -1: providing a link to documentation is rarely an adequate answer and in this case is not useful.

Comment: Can you provide more details on why you need the objectId Manoli? There's no way of retrieving it through our current native API but if we can understand the use case then we can either add that to our roadmap or recommend other workarounds.

Comment: Consider a case where you have a website and an accompanying mobile app. If you want the user to subscribe to topics on the website and receive updates for those topics on their mobile app, then for each user that subscribes to a topic the website will need to update their installation and subscribe them to the new channel (the topic they subscribed to). The recommended way to do this by Parse requires the installationId. There are workarounds (like subscribing each user to their own channel) but I was wondering if there was an easy way via the API to get the Id so that you didn't have to.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Manoli. There is currently no Forge API to get the installId to target a push to an individual user, so have a unique channel per user is the way to do this

Answer (score 1):

The installation ID is now available via a new API - [`forge.partners.parse.installationInfo`](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/partners/parse.html#installationinfo)