# Using Parse.com and advanced targeting push notifications with trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, parse-platform

I have gotten basic push notifications with `Parse.com` to work with `trigger.io`.

Now I'd like to take it to the next level and use advanced push targeting. More specifically I would like to target users within a certain distance from another user, to inform them that they have a friend nearby.

This looks quite straightforward with Parse's REST API: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/REST.

However, this would require me to save location data on my user's `Installation` objects and for that I need the `objectId`for the `Installation`.

I [read in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855996/get-objectid-after-parse-push-subscribe) that at that point in time (September 2012) one currently couldn't retreive the `objectId`.

Given my use case, would it be possible for you to provide a workaround or an estimate when such a feature could be added to `trigger.io`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new `forge.partners.parse.installationInfo` API is available in v1.4.31 of our platform - see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating an Installation object yourself using a REST call. As mentioned here: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#installations. In your case you will pass location as an additional parameter.

Comment: That won't do anything useful. You need the installationId in your installation object to match the installationId the device uses to listen for push notifications. This is something Trigger.io will have to support natively.

Comment: I believe Thomas Bouldin is correct. This would make trigger.io unusable for my app. I would have appreciated an official comment from the trigger.io team on this.